# Sequelize & mysql: clause `[tableName].deleted_at IS NULL` getting added automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

using mysql + sequelize in a React/Node app;

a where the clause below gets automatically added which is screwing up my other where clause statements

> [tableName].deleted_at IS NULL

in the nodeJS console, I can see the queries which all have this where clause...

tried recreating indexes, deleting this column throws an error that this field is not available;

column definition is:

```
`deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize models provide you with a table settings option called `paranoid`.
In short, it's providing you with a deleted state for each row in that table, and that flag will be included in every query while using the ORM methods to work with the DB on this model.
So when you set the paranoid option to true, deletedAt column will be added as date and time and null as default.

```
MyModel.init({ /* attributes here */ }, {
  sequelize,
  paranoid: true,

  // If you want to give a custom name to the deletedAt column
  deletedAt: 'destroyTime'
});
```

If you actually check the raw queries, you will find the addition to your WHERE statement `WHERE deletedAt IS NULL` on all the queries.

You can find out more from the official Sequelize documentation here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html